# Why does my code return a whole number even when it's not supposed to?

Tags: python, math, lambda

I'm doing a kata in Codewars where you have to make a function that takes in a string that is operator-like (Essentially the function takes in an operator-like string, for example, `"+"` and have to convert it to the matching operator, in this case, the Plus operator), and 2 values, `value1` and `value2`. Then, the function is supposed to turn those 3 into an equation and return the result of that equation (E.g: func("+", 50, 20) returns 70).

Screenshot:
[image: A screenshot]

The code:

```
def basic_op(operator, value1, value2):
    opFuncs = {"+": (lambda x,y: x+y),
           "-": (lambda x,y: x-y),
           "*": (lambda x,y: x*y),
           "/": (lambda x,y: x/y)
          }
    return int(opFuncs[operator] (value1, value2))
```

And everything else seems to go well except the error in red included in the screenshot. So in that instance my function returned `0` but it must be `0.005101...`. Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning: `int(opFuncs[operator] (value1, value2))`

the int() is making your return value an integer, meaning it is discarding the decimal places.

Try returning: `float(opFuncs[operator] (value1, value2))`

Comment: wow, I didn't expect that to be the mistake. I guess I haven't understood Python fundamentals after all. Thank you so much!